# How works python property factory and nested functions

Tags: python

In the section "Coding a property factory" of 《fluent python》，the code as follow：

```
 
def quantity(storage_name):
```

```
    def qty_getter(instance):  # B   
        return instance.__dict__[storage_name]   

    def qty_setter(instance, value):   
        if value > 0:
            instance.__dict__[storage_name] = value   
        else:
            raise ValueError('value must be > 0')

    return property(qty_getter, qty_setter)
```

`class LineItem:
    weight = quantity('weight')   # A
    price = quantity('price')`

def __init__(self, description, weight, price):
        self.description = description
        self.weight = weight   
        self.price = price

    def subtotal(self):
        return self.weight * self.price

In the "A" only pass a argument,but in the function quantity receive two arguments：storage_name and instance. I am confused that the argument "instance" in the "B" how it passed to the qty_getter

Comment: For some reason whoever wrote this used `instance` for the first argument of the method rather than the conventional `self`. It's just `self` with a different name. It's a reference to the instance the method is being called on, passed in by Python, same as in `subtotal` in the `LineItem` class.

Comment: in the future, please post code directly.. not pictures

Comment: @kindall that is not quite right, as we have nested functions here, not a class.

Comment: It's the same thing. The function is going to be a method.

Answer (score 1):

The function `quantity` builds and returns a property instance defined by the statement `return property(qty_getter, qty_setter)`.

The property itself is built enclosing two nested functions `qty_getter` and `qty_setter`. Enclosing functions can access to the parent's function arguments (in a way similar to closures).

When you call `self.weight` (in the subtotal function) you are telling python to call the getter function (`qty_getter`) of the property assigned to `self.weight`.

To the getter (or setter) function, by property contract, is provided the instance of the object that holds the property itself (LineItem in this case) that in turn can access to the `storage_name` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `property` in Python is a special decorator. Decorators are simply put functions that are wrapping an other object, usually class fields.

The hard to understand bit is that the `quantity` above is not a class, but a function. Inside that function there is two nested functions: `qty_getter` and `qty_setter`. Note that in your class you are only using the outer function directly. That `quantity` function returns the outcome of

```
property(qty_getter, qty_setter)
```

`property` here is a Python builtin that behaves in a special way. Whenever you try to set the value of the property, the `qty_setter` is called with the new value. When you want to get the current value, the `qty_getter` is called.

Since the property is bound to a class, you will usually call it on that class' instances, e.g.:

```
line = LineItem()
line.weight = 10  # weight setter called here
print(line.price)  # price getter called here
line.subtotal   # this method accesses both getters
```

Whenever you access a class' field in Python, internally that field is looked up using a helper method. The property is overriding the default behaviour here and instead calls the functions defined in the property. The `instance` you see there as argument is an instance of `LineItem`. It is comparable to `self` in normal methods, except you are accessing an other object's `self` here.